# how can i get real hex values of vdso outputs

Tags: ida, disassembly, debugging

I'm trying to get an algorithm in a program but i can't see the hex codes.
At the moment i break all debug checks it fully debugging but i can't see how it creates the request.

[image: here is a screenshot to get better view]

Comment: Please describe in greater detail what you are trying to achieve and what problem you are having. The description provided is not very clear.